# Apple Mac M2: Rosetta 2 update is not available

Tags: ventura, rosetta

I am trying to install Rosetta 2 on a brand new Mac with macOS 13.4.1 by keying in the command:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

However, Rosetta 2 does not get installed and errors out as:
Rosetta 2 update is not available

How to resolve this?

Comment: Are you running your Mac behind a corporate firewall? Do other software updates work?

Comment: What happens if you just try to launch whatever Intel app you have? Same?

Comment: Yes, software update works, the machine is behind a corporate firewall ... when I try to install the App through GUI, the error is same

Comment: The corporate firewall maybe blocks the connection. Try with a different network, or talk to the firewall people.